# Django Formset con 'agregado' dinamico de forms

Tags: python, django

Imagen de como luce el html, al apretar el + no ocurre nada, en cambio si agrego "Extra" y apreto el "-" si saca los formularios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy teniendo un problema con un formulario dinámico en Django usando formsets.

Estuve viendo este tutorial: 
https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

Y de ahí saque el código base, pero no me funciona como debería, **no puedo agregar** mas forms para cargarlos de una.

Creo que el problema esta en el javascript, pero al no saber mucho de esto no puedo solucionarlo.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

**forms.py**

```
OrdenCompraModelFormset = modelformset_factory(
    OrdenCompraProducto,
    fields=[
        'tipo_producto',
        'cantidad',
        'fecha_entrega',
        'proveedor_surgerido',
    ],
    extra=1,
    widgets={
        'fecha_entrega': forms.DateInput(attrs=
                                         {'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'date'}),
    }
)
```

**views.py**

```
def formv_ordencompra(request):
form=OrdenCompraForm, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('0')
        formset = OrdenCompraModelFormset(queryset=OrdenCompraProducto.objects.none())
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print('1')
        formset = OrdenCompraModelFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset_obj = formset.save(commit=False)
            ordencompra = OrdenCompra.objects.create()

            for form_obj in formset_obj:
                form_obj.orden = ordencompra
                form_obj.save()
            messages.success(request, f'La orden fue cargada!')
            return redirect('.')
    else:
        print('2')
        formset = OrdenCompraModelFormset()
    return render(request, 'webapp/formularios/ordencompra.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**ordencompra.html**

```
{% extends 'webapp/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_principal %}


    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Cargar "Orden de devolucion"</h1>
        <p class="mb-4">Esta orden define quien trae y cuando un recurso que este en obra</p>
        <p class="mb-4">¿Cuando cargar?: En el momento en el que se quieran traer recursos desde obra</p>

        <hr>





        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}

                <div class="row form-row spacer">
                    <div class="input-group">


                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger remove-form-row">-</button>
                        </div>


                        {{form|crispy}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>

            {% endfor %}

            <div class="row spacer">
                <div class="">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


    </div>


{% endblock %}


{% block content_plugins %}

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
            var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
            var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
            if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
            if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
            if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        }
        function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
            var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
            var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                var id = 'id_' + name;
                $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
            });
            newElement.find('label').each(function() {
                var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
                if (forValue) {
                    forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total-1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                    $(this).attr({'for': forValue});
                }
            });
            total++;
            $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
            $(selector).after(newElement);
            var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
            conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
                .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
            return false;
        }
        function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
            var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            if (total > 1){
                btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
                var forms = $('.form-row');
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
                for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
                    $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function() {
                        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                    });
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        $(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
            return false;
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteForm('form', $(this));
            return false;
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

A mi me funcionó este ejemplo 
https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d

Espero te ayude.